# Making a API call from ArcGIS Arcade script

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I have a javascript code to make an API call as below.

```
            const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "http://ServiceURL?ID=" + pid);
            request.send();
```

Now my requirement is to make the same service call from ArcGIS Arcade script?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am new to ArcGIS Archade Script!!!

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible with Arcade.

*Arcade is a portable, lightweight, and secure expression language written for use in the ArcGIS platform. Like other expression languages, it can perform mathematical calculations, manipulate text, and evaluate logical statements.*  It doesn't not support making external requests like XMLHttpRequest.

https://developers.arcgis.com/arcade/

Comment: Thank you for your response.